# FIWARE IoT Agent is changing the service path of incoming message

Tags: iot, fiware, fiware-orion

We are currently using the VernemQ MQTT server in conjunction with a FIWARE stack that comprises the IoT Agent and Orion Context Broker. When sending data to the IoT Agent, we utilize the message topic format **api-key/device-id/attrs**.

When the IoT Agent receives a message on this topic, it uses the provided '**api-key**' to determine both the service path and service name. Once these values are determined, the payload is then forwarded to the Orion Context Broker using the **v2/entities/** API.

Our setup works perfectly when the data rate is relatively low, around 40,000 records per hour. However, when the data rate increases to approximately 80,000 records per hour, we've noticed that the IoT Agent appears to change the service provider from, for example, '**serviceProvider1**' to '**serviceProviderXy**'.

We're currently at a loss as to why this change is occurring, and it is causing significant security concerns for our system. We would greatly appreciate any insights or assistance in understanding and resolving this issue.

We tried running multiple tests with higher data rate(>=80k records per hour)  and observed in all the tests this phenomenon is common. When we run tests with lesser data rate, this is not occuring.

- iotagent-node-lib: 2.18.0 version.
- iotagent-json: 1.20.0 version.
- Orion: 3.4.0 version.

Comment: Measures management has been refactored in recent version. Is this issue happening with last version (json/ul) 2.3.0?